# How the input to store enhancer is provided in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Store enhancers seem like extension methods in C#, since they add functionality to a Redux data store. Although in most projects, middlewares are enough to modify the behavior of the data store, but the question is:

- when is it best to define a store enhancer?
- how the input to a store enhancer is provided?

Let's consider the following sample enhancer which tends to dispatch actions asynchronously:

```
export const asyncEnhancer = delay => createStoreFunction => (...args) => {    
    const store = createStoreFunction(...args);    
    return {       
         ...store,        
         dispatchAsync: (action) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
              setTimeout(() => { 
                   store.dispatch(action);  
                   resolve();
              }, delay);  
         })
    }; 
}
```

**In the above code, what value is passed to createStoreFunction  and args  ?**

As for applying this enhancer, imagine we have:

```
export default createStore(myCombinedReducer,    
    compose(applyMiddleware(m1, m2, thunk), asyncEnhancer(2000)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question above, included a simple store enhancer just to dispatch actions asynchronously.

As a Redux API, ***applyMiddleware*** is also **considered as store enhancer** and is the only store enhancer that's included in the Redux library which enables you to wrap the store's dispatch method. According to the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware), the store enhancer signature is :

**`createStore => createStore`**

As a result, having a look at the implementation code of applyMiddleware from [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/src), will give a great idea on how the input to a store enhancer is provided:

```
export default function applyMiddleware(...middlewares) {
  return createStore => (...args) => {
    const store = createStore(...args)
    let dispatch = () => {
      throw new Error(
        'Dispatching while constructing your middleware is not allowed. ' +
          'Other middleware would not be applied to this dispatch.'
      )
    }

    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState: store.getState,
      dispatch: (...args) => dispatch(...args)
    }
    const chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI))
    dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch)

    return {
      ...store,
      dispatch
    }
  }
}
```

The code above, clearly shows the signature `createStore => createStore`.

applyMiddlaware API returns a function and as soon as you input a createStore into it, it expects you to provide the arguments similar to what is usually provided for createStore API.

So, that's why we can use this shorter notation:

```
const myStore=applyMiddleware(thunk,logger)(createStore)(rootReducer)
```

than this longer one:

```
const middlewares = [
  thunk,
  logger
]

const myStore = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
)
```

Although in most projects, writing middleware is satisfactory enough, but it's useful to have a high-level understanding of what a store enhancer is.